# Dispatcher.Invoke and accessing textbox from another thread

Tags: vb.net

I am having a little trouble understanding how I should be utilizing the Dispatcher to help me solve my problem of accessing a text box from a different thread.  What I am trying to achieve is getting the thread to append to a chat box once it receives data form the server.

```
Public Class ChatScreen

Public client As Client

Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    client = Application.Current.Properties("Client")
    Me.Title = "ChitChat - " & client.Name

    txtMessage.Focus()

    Dim serverHandler As New ServerHandler(client.clientSocket, client.networkStream, txtChat)
End Sub

Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
    client.SendMessage(txtMessage.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Window_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.Key = Key.Enter Then
        client.SendMessage(txtMessage.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub AppendToChat(ByVal message As String)
    txtChat.AppendText(">> " & message)
End Sub

Public Class ServerHandler

    Dim clientSocket As TcpClient
    Public networkStream As NetworkStream
    Dim thread As Thread

    Public Sub New(ByVal clientSocket As TcpClient, ByVal networkStream As NetworkStream)
        Me.clientSocket = clientSocket
        Me.networkStream = networkStream
        thread = New Thread(AddressOf ListenForServer)
        thread.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Sub ListenForServer()
        Dim bytesFrom(10024) As Byte
        Dim message As String

        While True
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, CInt(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
            message = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)
            message = message.Substring(0, message.IndexOf("$"))

            'AppendToChat <--- This is where I would like to append the message to the text box
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

You  can use SynchronizationContext to do this, 
Store UI tread context in a variable like this

```
Private syncContext As SynchronizationContext
Private Sub frmClient_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    syncContext = AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext
End Sub
```

Now create a procedure to execute on main UI thread like this

```
Private Sub AddTextBox()
    ‘Do whatever you want you are in UI thread here

End Sub
```

From you background thread post request on UI thread like this

```
syncContext.Post(New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf AddTextBox), Nothing)
```

you can even pass arguments also

```
Private Sub AddTextBox(ByVal argument As Object)
    ‘Do whatever you want you are in UI thread here

End Sub

.....
syncContext.Post(New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf AddTextBox), objToPass)
```